# Why could SparkSession initialization take longer every iteration in a single application?

Tags: apache-spark

I use spark for batch analysis.

I run Spark on a standalone Ubuntu server with 128G memory and 32-core CPU. Run `spark-sumbit my_code.py` without any additional configuration parameters.

In a while loop I start `SparkSession`, analyze data and then stop the context and this process repeats every 10 seconds.

```
while True:
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("sync_task").config('spark.driver.maxResultSize' , '5g').getOrCreate()
    sc = spark.sparkContext

    #some process and analyze

    spark.stop()
```

When program starts, it works perfectly.

but when it works for many hours. spark initialization take long time.
it makes 10 or 20 seconds for just initializing spark.

So what is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You use a single-JVM `local` run mode. I can't explain exactly what happens in your case, but it's not surprising to see this single JVM being more and more under pressure for memory. It starts clean and over time Spark leaves some temporary objects before they get GCed.

I strongly recommend attaching [jconsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) to see the JVM metrics and monitor memory and CPU usage.

Comment: So what is the solution, if memory or CPU usage increases, what should I do for handle this problem ?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Also [SPARK-20352](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20352?jql=project%20%3D%20SPARK) (clearly opened by the OP).

Comment: @JacekLaskowski which metrics should I monitor in Jconsole for memory usage and CPU usage?